# Node Js / Gulp task explaination

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am new to Node. js and Gulp. This is in reference to the following section of gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('scripts-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.vendorJavascript.concat(paths.appJavascript, paths.appTemplates))
    .pipe(plugins.if(/html$/, buildTemplates()))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmpJavascript))
    .pipe(plugins.connect.reload());
});
```

Can someone please explain the meaning of 
"plugins.if(/html$/, buildTemplates()"

Comment: use input from above paths and , if exist folder (/html) then process the node stream thru "buildTemplates"..... ie buildTemplates has a dependency on exists('/html').

Comment: What does $/ stand for in '/html$/' ?

Comment: not positive on the gulp API . IMO its just a regex string that gets matched against the projects canonical html folder and its contents .

Comment: I would say that that if the filepath ends with html - hence the $ to indicate the end of the filepath string - it passes the if condition.